# Is it possible to record audio with OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, directshow, video-capture, audio-recording

I am trying to record a video in OpenCV from a stream such as a webcam with audio. I am currently writing the application to use DirectShow to grab data from the stream and to pass that data into an `IplImage*`. This is great for creating the video file, but what if I would like to include audio? Do I have to use another library to write out the small amount of audio information?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a purpose of OpenCV library.

Comment: So I would have to use DirectShow to get my video data and push that into OpenCV and then use DirectShow to save out audio separately. Afterwards I would need another application to merge the 2 together?

Comment: @Seb Yes, to record both streams (audio and video) you can capture them with DirectShow then process video frame with OpenCV and finally save processed video & audio streams with DirectShow (or FFMPEG). You can merge them in the same application or as separate post-processing step as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll figure out the best method from here